# Detecting in MS Access when the user has filled a standard plain or rich text box but kept typing

Tags: ms-access-2010

Is there a way to detect when a user has filled a field completely while they are typing? I've instances of users 'losing data' because they've typed up to the end of the rich (or plain) text (bound or unbound) box and not noticed that the last piece of text they "entered" wasn't saved, so I'd like to pop up a warning when they fill the box.

I've tested, and hitting the end of a text box doesn't trigger any error at all (such as 6 - Overflow). I'm loath to set explicit validation rules on every text box in the application.

Comment: Strange, I just tested a (plain) text box bound to a `Text(5)` field and Access would not let me type more than 5 characters. Once the field was full, each keypress just made the computer go "ding".

Comment: @GordThompson Do you have the Provide Feedback with Sound option set under Options > Client Settings? I don't (and suspect many of my users won't as they only have Access Runtme not full office).

Comment: Nope, no little tick mark beside "Provide feedback with sound". (To be honest, I've never fiddled with that setting.)

Comment: Odd. In a 255-char text box (i.e. no length stated) I can type to the end and no further but get not visual or audible feedback. Same with a 5-char text box. It just swallows the characters after the 5th. Might depend on what sound scheme you have set on the PC, I suppose, but I've tried a few (including explicitly enabling sounds for Program Error). Still nada.

Comment: What kind of database are you connecting to? I think I've seen this behavior with some ODBC drivers already. I think the ability for the textbox to limit input length depends on the type of datasource you're using.

Comment: @HK1 The back end database is an access accdb file.